# Is it possible to do that with vertical scroll collection view or table view ?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

Can somebody give advice about this ? I prefer the vertical scrolling.

Comment: Get advice from your parent or a friend as to whether your question makes sense before posting a question at a public web site.

Comment: Which part did not make sense to you? I can fix it, but you too Tomato.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's android and I can't really post entire code, you can probably look at this link for help -

http://sdroid.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/fixed-header-in-tablelayout.html

I would suggest going for table view since collection view is generally for grid layouts. Since your layout looks more like a list of items stacked in one column, table view will be ideal and a little simpler. If you want more complex layout Collection view is much better.

According to apple docs -

> A table view displays a list of items in a single column. UITableView
>   is a subclass of UIScrollView, which allows users to scroll through
>   the table, although UITableView allows vertical scrolling only. The
>   cells comprising the individual items of the table are UITableViewCell
>   objects; UITableView uses these objects to draw the visible rows of
>   the table. Cells have content—titles and images—and can have, near the
>   right edge, accessory views. Standard accessory views are disclosure
>   indicators or detail disclosure buttons; the former leads to the next
>   level in a data hierarchy and the latter leads to a detailed view of a
>   selected item. Accessory views can also be framework controls, such as
>   switches and sliders, or can be custom views. Table views can enter an
>   editing mode where users can insert, delete, and reorder rows of the
>   table.

Comment: Actually before asking this question,I tryed many things that I think.I used a table view with a custom header view then set the height to 1,set negative constant constraint to the label inside the header view, set the table view cell content clipToBounds to true, maybe the label carries out.However,it didnt work.If I can get the label out inside the header view, everything will be solved.

Comment: Added a link in my answer that can help